# Maven dependencies could not be resolved: ruled out proxy cause

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run [this example code](https://github.com/jiayuasu/GeoSparkTemplateProject) (Java template project) in Eclipse on Linux Mint 19. Maven (`Apache Maven 3.6.0`), Java (`openjdk version "1.8.0_222"`, `Java version: 1.8.0_222` associated with Maven), Spark (`version 2.4.4`) are all installed.
every time I attempt to build the project, I get this error after it attempts to download `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom`:

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6:
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
connect timed out -> [Help 1]
```

I saw that other people had the same issue and fixed their proxy in `settings.xml`, I did the same but I am still getting this error (Eclipse is configured with the same proxy settings):

```xml
<proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>my.proxy.here</host>
  <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
<proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>https</protocol>
  <host>my.proxy.here</host>
  <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
```

Does this plugin need to be listed in the `pom.xml` file? Currently only `maven-shade-plugin` is present.

If that's not the issue, what could it be?

Thanks

**EDIT**
The output of `curl repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` is:

```html
<html>
<head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
<body>
<h1>302 Moved Temporarily</h1>
<ul>
<li>Code: Found</li>
<li>Message: Resource Found</li>
<li>RequestId: E0DE40F4A926069A</li>
<li>HostId: 63yyk2SNKS3jDdCAcBvpXVdklrEzexv7u6b0kcGB1e7Aogtdnk33ay39I0d8wRfg5VUgoHJcMU4=</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just curious what happens if you curl https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 from the machine having the problem?  Also, do you actually have a proxy?

Comment: @JJF I'll add the output to the curl command to my question, and yes, I do have a proxy, I'm on a business network and everything is super secure. I copied the proxy settings from my conf files that I need to use to access the web.

Comment: This is most probably a network issue. Maybe a firewall blocking certain programs from accessing certain urls. I myself know cases where I could access a url through the browser but not through Maven because certain User Agents were blocked or obstructed.

Comment: Found the solution! Apparently all I needed to do was add a `settings.xml` file in the `.m2/` folder and fill it with the same settings as in the other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: it turns out that I needed to create a `settings.xml` in my `/home/name/.m2/` folder and fill it with the same settings as in `/etc/maven/settings.xml`

(side note: also don't use "http(s)" in the proxy addresses)

Comment: @TheHeadRush I will as asoon as the UI lets me (there's a two day wait apprently)